# Handling errors of undefined URLs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, routes

My frontend log is full of these errors. 
When I hit any undefined address I got this in my terminal (in the vscode not in the browser).
The main problem is I'm not sure how to handle errors that are caused by hitting an undefined url. For example here I know that `/ca/en/category` is undefined and doesn't exist but I don't know how to stop js from trying to map this undefined URL.

```
    error: {
  "requestedPath": "/ca/en/category", (or any other unefined address)
  "errorMessage": "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined",
  "clientIp": "::1"
}
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at Chrome.module.exports../src/components/Chrome.tsx.Chrome.render (...\dist\server.js:518:916)
    at processChild (...\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:2207:18)
    at resolve (...\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:2064:5)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (...\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:2383:22)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (...\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:2357:19)
    at Object.renderToString (...\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:2729:25)
    at...\dist\server.js:4346:69
    at step (...\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:133:27)
    at Object.next (...\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:114:57)
    at fulfilled (...e\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:104:62)
```

and here is how I'm building addresses (for category):

```
    if (pathname.startsWith('/category/')) {
        const cat = menu.find(({ slug }) => pathname.startsWith('/category/' + slug));
        if (cat) {
            leftBar = cat.subcategories.map(({ name, productLines, slug: subSlug }) => ({
                title: name,
                path: `/category/${cat.slug}/${subSlug}`,
                links: productLines.map(({ name, slug }) => ({
                    title: name,
                    path: `/category/${cat.slug}/${subSlug}/${slug}`,
                })),
            }));
            leftBarTitle = cat.name;
        }
    }
```

and I have a server,js file and in line 518 I have:

```
        return _react2.default.createElement(_react2.default.Fragment, null, banner && this.state.bannerOpen ? _react2.default.createElement(_Banner2.default, { banner: banner, onClose: this.handleBannerClose }) : null, _react2.default.createElement("div", { className: classes.frame }, _react2.default.createElement(_CssBaseline2.default, null), _react2.default.createElement(_TopBar2.default, null), _react2.default.createElement("div", { className: classes.container, id: "container" }, _react2.default.createElement("div", { className: classes.content }, children), pathname.startsWith('/category') && _react2.default.createElement("div", { className: classes.leftBar }, leftBarTitle && _react2.default.createElement(_react2.default.Fragment, null, _react2.default.createElement(_Typography2.default, { variant: "headline", component: "span" }, leftBarTitle), _react2.default.createElement("p", null)), leftBar.map(function (_a, i) {
        var title = _a.title,
            path = _a.path,
            links = _a.links;
```

I think there shouldn't be errors like this in the terminal but I'm not sure how to handle it.

Comment: Just means one of the values you are mapping over dosnt exist. Either cat.subcategories, or productlines. Putting in some console logs on those should reveal what's going one, they need to be arrays.

Comment: @SpeedOfRound I don't have /category url and I think that's why it is throwing this error. I just don't know have to handle it. Because I don't want the errors to be in my terminal.

Comment: changing your third line to  if (cat.subcategories) Should prevent you from getting to that step

Comment: @HardikModha I'm asking about how to handle undefined url errors not ` Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Comment: This is when you run the map method over a variable which is not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In render you always need to return something so that's the way I solved the issue:

```
            if (cat) {....
        } else {
            return <Redirect to="/" />;
```

doing so, it will redirect me to an address and won't give me `Nothing was returned from render.` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

just try this code and look where you try to map `undefined` object

```
if(!cat.subcategories) console.log('not exist but i try to map')

cat.subcategories.map(({ name, productLines, slug: subSlug }) => {  
    if(!productLines) console.log('not exist but i try to map')

})`
```

Comment: I added the code but I'm not seeing any output of it.

Answer (score 0):

you can validate with:

```
if(!cat.subcategories) return
```

Comment: ` Cannot read property 'subcategories' of undefined` when I'm hitting an undefined url

Comment: I also tried `if(!cat) return` and the result is `Nothing was returned from render.`